# Setting values to AngularJS scope labels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph

Hi I am trying to create bar graph using angular js here my requirement is to get data from url and show as bar graph

I need to get suitename and set to $scope.labels actually I need to set values as

```
$scope.labels = ['test a', 'test b', 'test c'];
```

but what my code is doing is

`$scope.labels = ["'test a', 'test b', 'test c'"]`

(quotes in begging and ending); (when I inspect in firebug, console.log seems to be correct) total 3 names are considered as 1 string because I am appending to variable due to this my bar graph x-axis showing only 1 long name instead of 3 names is there any way to achieve this below is my code what i have tried

```
app.controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var apiResponse = $http.get("http://166.62.36.83/DataService/DataService.asmx/GetSuiteCoverageJson?testsuiteid=9");

        apiResponse.success(function(responseData, status, headers, config) {   
            var testSuiteName = "";
            var totalAutomationCases = "";  
            for (var i = 0, l = responseData.length; i < l; i++) {
                testSuiteName = testSuiteName + "\'"+ responseData[i].testSuiteName +"\'" +",";
                totalAutomationCases = totalAutomationCases + "'"+responseData[i].totalAutomationCases +"'" +",";
                //$scope.labels = [responseData[i].testSuiteName];
                console.log(testSuiteName.substring(0,testSuiteName.length-1)); 
            }
            $scope.labels = [testSuiteName.substring(0,testSuiteName.length-1)];

             console.log(totalAutomationCases.substring(0,totalAutomationCases.length-1));
             console.log(testSuiteName.substring(0,testSuiteName.length-1));
              $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
              $scope.data = [
                ['2','4','1']
              ];
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you overcompensated the task. No need to concatenate strings like you are doing it, you in fact create one big string. If you need *an array* of names you can simply do something like this:

```
$scope.labels = responseData.map(function(el) {
    return el.testSuiteName;
});
```

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is very convenient here.

Comment: can u also suggest me how to set values to $scope.data I have tried the same as u suggested above like 
$scope.data = responseData.map(function(el) {
     return el.testSuiteName;
    });
but I am getting Error: t is undefined in firebug any solution?

Comment: What is `t` variable?

Comment: No idea I thinks it is in  inner implementation of angular js . However is the same logic works for setting data also?

Comment: map is native javascript method. What is content of the `responseData`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a quick fix would be:

```
$scope.labels = testSuiteName.replace(/'/g, "").split(",")
```

That is, if you're hellbent on creating one big string instead of processing each entry as a string and pushing it into an array.

Comment: It should if testSuiteName = "'test a', 'test b', 'test c'", you can try it in the console, just type "'test a', 'test b', 'test c'".replace(/'/g, "").split(",") the first replace command removes all ', then the second splits it into an array using the seperator ,